# Avoid Duplicate values for INSERT in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this code to insert something in the table but every time if you visit the home page it duplicates the insert so I have 6 'VIP' and I just should have one.

Which change should I do in the code? - If you have 'Badge_ID - VIP' you don't get it anymore.

```php
<?php 
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users_badges` (`user_id`, `badge_id`, `badge_slot`) VALUES ('$my_id', 'VIP', '1')");
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It's helpful when asking questions about databases to show the table definition.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: Well you just show us your php code. Not the table definition of your table in which you insert your data. This means, we need your `CREATE TABLE` Statement to give you a useful hint.

Comment: you can handle this in two way :- One at sql level to add unique key or composite primary key or at code level to check before insert.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, you don't want rows with the same `user_id` and `badge_id` values.  To prevent this, create a unique index:

```
create unique index idx_users_badges_2 on users_badges(user_id, badge_id);
```

This will prevent duplicate rows.  The `insert` will generate an error.  You can ignore the error in your code or prevent it using `insert ignore` or `insert . . . on duplicate key update`.